# Selenium not managing to find the keyword in the website

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Basically, I'm trying to get the program to find the keyword, and if it manages to do it, it will click the link to the pdf file in the page (for now i just want to print a confirmation message)

But, despite the keyword clearly being in the page, selenium can't manage to find it.

Here's the block of code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


url = 'https://www.bursamalaysia.com/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=3434107'
driver.get(url)

try:
    
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.TAG_NAME, "body"), "Annual Audited Accounts"))

    print("Found: Annual Audited Accounts")
except:
    print("Text not found")


driver.quit()
```

I've tried all sorts of search methods, including XPath and JavaScript, but I literally can't search for it.

I'm currently using Selenium on PyCharm fyi

Comment: You wanted to read the text from the PDF or from the website ? Can you clarify your ask ?

Comment: @Akzy i want to read the text from the PDF, but currently that's not the point. I have a bunch of links that i want to check, and all the links im interested in has the 'Annual Audited Accounts' text, so before selenium clicks the link, the website first needs to have that text in it, hence what my block of code currently is for

Answer (score 1):

You just need to handle the [IFRAMES](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/#:%7E:text=Iframes%20allow%20the%20insertion%20of,and%20are%20still%20commonly%20used.&text=However%2C%20if%20there%20are%20no,in%20the%20top%20level%20document.)

Check the working code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.bursamalaysia.com/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=3434107'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

try:
    # Below line will switch into the IFRAME
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "bm_ann_detail_iframe")))
    wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.TAG_NAME, "body"), "Annual Audited Accounts"))
    print("Found: Annual Audited Accounts")
except:
    print("Text not found")

# Below line will come out of the IFRAME
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.quit()
```

Result:

```
Found: Annual Audited Accounts

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Because the keyword **Annual Audited Accounts** is part of an iframe which selenium cannot access directly, you need to first switch to the iframe

[image]

add below code to swtich to ifrma first    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.NAME,'announcement_detail_iframe'))

Full Code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Initialize WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

url = 'https://www.bursamalaysia.com/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=3434107'
driver.get(url)

try:
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.NAME,'announcement_detail_iframe'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.TAG_NAME, "body"), "Annual Audited Accounts"))

    print("Found: Annual Audited Accounts")
except:
    print("Text not found")


driver.quit()
```

Prints

```
Found: Annual Audited Accounts
```